# DOM contains old element after page update

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome Extension (no knowledge required for this question...) and when I visit a page with a certain domain, I have a script that is ran. All is does is grab the `attribute` value from a `<meta>` tag in the page:

```
$('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').attr('content')
```

This works fine on the first page load. However, located within the page there is also links to related content. If I click one of the related links, the Chrome spinner spins a bit, loads the new content, and updates the URL in the address bar.

However, if I try the above jQuery, I get the old attribute value, not the new one on the new page. Upon using Chrome's `Inspect Element`, I see that the old attribute value is there, but the new one is there if I use `view page source` instead.

So it seems that the DOM is old...is there a good way to get an updated DOM? This question goes along with all of the other questions of `DOM vs Page Source are different` threads that I've looked at but didn't get any answers from.

Is there a good way to get a new DOM with the updated attribute?  Thanks.

Edit: Here's what the chrome extension code looks like:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
    // request current page , `cache:false`
    $.ajax({url:window.location.href, cache:false})
    .done(function(data) {
    var content = $(data).filter("meta[itemprop=contentURL]").attr("content");
    console.log(content);
  });
});
```

The above code logs `undefined`. Still looking for a good workaround unless the proposed solution is the best one.

Comment: It sounds like the page you are on is updating the visible content dynamically via AJAX instead of navigating to a new page. Most sites don't bother updating the meta data since bots/etc generally request pages anew.

Comment: @abraham - thanks for the response. That is definitely possible and wouldn't surprise me in the least. Any good way to work around that or is guest271314's answer below a good way to go?

Comment: The fact that you don't see the updated information on inspect means it's NOT updated in the DOM. Your content script cannot access the "updated" information. The proposed solution might work, when you debug it - it creates a fresh request (just like "view source" does) for that URL. I would look for alternative ways of finding what you need though.

Comment: The only other solution that I could think of would be to refresh the tab (since the URL is updated) and then send the content script again.

Comment: @joshft91 That would probably be a very jarring user experience.

Comment: Certainly not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try

v2 (javascript)

```
function done() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var content = this.responseText;
  div.innerHTML = content;
  content = div.querySelectorAll("meta[itemprop*=contentURL]")[0].content;
  console.log(content);
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = done;
request.open("GET", window.location.href + "?=" + (new Date().getTime()), false);
request.send();
```

v1 (javascript utilizing jquery)

```
// request current page , `cache:false`
$.ajax({url:window.location.href, cache:false})
.done(function(data) {
  var content = $(data).filter("meta[itemprop=contentURL]").attr("content");
  console.log(content);
});
```

See [jQuery-ajax-settings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) at `cache`

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I have a little time. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I updated the main post to reflect what my code looks like with your suggestion. Every time I click on a related content, it's fired, but the console logs `undefined`, so I'm not sure what might be going on.

Comment: `undefined` was `jquery` ? , unless was included in `manifest` , `content_scripts`. Posted v1 at post due to jquery being a "tag" at Question.

Comment: The `console.log(content)` was `undefined`. jQuery is being loaded up in my `manifest.json` file so it should be executing. I'll try your v2, but I'm not sure where the funciton `done()` gets called - unless I'm missing it somewhere.

Comment: With reference to v1, to be certain jQuery loaded , could try `alert(jQuery().jquery)` ? Also , try change `url` to full path of page , and reduce to only `.filter("meta")` ? At v2 `request.onload = done;` calls `done()` . Thanks